How to design this shape?
the model is available for free here:
https://makerworld.com/en/models/13717#profileId-13429
The cylinder part of the base could be created using 2 coils to create the edges and loft them together, then circular pattern the single fin, flip and repeat; but how to close out the top into a dome?




Wrong place to ask nothing to do with making 2D graphic items to communicate with people. Try engineering or 3D printing.  You might still get an answer but the pool of people who do this here is shallow. anyway its just a spiral

This is complex - especially, when one tries to use simple programs. I do not have Autodesk Fusion, but at least something resembling can be made by using lightweight 3D software (Moi, version 5 beta in this case)
You wanted to insert caps to the boxes which are formed when your coil stripes cross each other. But the caps should not be straight, they should be bulged like lenses and those caps together make the actual surface.
I'm afraid there's no easy way to insert the wanted bulged caps as a drawing rule, because your shape is already degraded to polygon mesh - it contains no more  math formula info of the original coil curves. You must make and place the caps (hundreds of them) manually one by one.
It's better to make one box, insert the cap to it and then generate the whole surface as a tiled pattern. The spherical dome top can be made by inserting a deformation (if such deformation is possible to be defined and inserted with the available tools).
The edges of the coil stripes must be wavy from the start. It's difficult to deform them later. I started from this XY-plane shape:

It's 16 copies of identical rectangles which have one side stretched to a curve. To use them easily I made a Boolean union.
I twisted the union around the X-axis to get one 360 degree coil stripe:

The next step is to make 8 piece circular pattern of it and insert a flipped duplicate of the pattern. The idea is to follow your experiment to see, how the stripes actually cross each other:

To separate one box the stripes must be sliced in each crossing. Boolean Merge did it. I saved only one box, the rest were deleted. It's in the left in the next image:

The right half shows the inserted cap. It's made by sweeping between 2 top edges of the box (highlighted, yellow temporarily). The rest 2 edges are sweep rails.
As well one could generate a fill patch between all 4 edges.
As you surely guess, it took a while to see that the coil stripes cross at the right place when there was 16 identical original XY-plane gravestone-like shapes and there was total as many coil stripes - 8 twisted to clockwise and 8 to counterclocwise.
The walls of the box are now useless, I deleted them. The surface cap is colored darker, because white is hard to see. The surface cap alone is in the left in the next image:

In the right the cap is copied to a 8-piece circular pattern around X-axis.
In the next image in the left the pattern is duplicated and the duplicate is rotated 22,5 degrees (that's 360 degrees/16). The rotated duplicate snaps perfectly at the edge of the 1st copy when moved to X-direction:

In the right a long tube is made by duplicating, moving and finally combining the pieces to a Boolean union to get a single shape. The ragged end is just under shaving. A vertical plane is inserted to slice off the ragged area.
The surface tube is placed inside a straight base form reference cylinder (green). The brown cylinder with curved end will be used as deformation reference:

In the next image the wavy surface is flown inside the deformation reference. The deformation reference is removed to see the result:

The pole of the dome has a small fill patch. The deformation reference was made a little too long. It left a little hole around the pole. It was needed to prevent a math singularity which would cause the deformation calculation to diverge.
This construction unfortunately makes different pattern to the curved end when compared to your lamp image. It needs more than only radial scaling. The curved end needs simultaneous progeressive radial and axial scaling. This is a blind alley, because there's no way to input the needed formula for the axial scaling. But this one might be useful when one wants to 3D-print food; in this case a premium sausage encased to a net.
I do not know if Autodesk Fusion is any better. I guess Blender doesn't have this limitation. I'll return if I find a way to make it look right in simple programs with the available geometric transformations.
LATE ADDITION: A little better curved end is possible with different tiling & transformation order. It's still not perfect, but the proportions of the surface elements do not step wrong as steeply:

In addition it's easy to make a groove between the surface elements.
The main idea is to tile onto XY-plane rectangular surface elements, which have the needed material thickness, top surface curvature and the decorative groove between the elements. The progressive axial scaling is made before the planar jacket is bent; at first to cylindrical and then a part of it to have the curved dome top.
The starting point is to make one surface element:

In the left a square is extruded to have some thickness. The square has X and Y direction diagonals; both diagonals were drawn 8 mm long. In the middle a sphere is placed partially over it to make the spherical top surface by applying Boolean intersection. In the right the intersection is applied.
The grooves between the surface elements can be made by adding (=Boolean Union) a little shrinked copy to the surface element. The reduction scaling is to 95%:

It's difficult to tile a number of these. It becomes much easier if the element is sliced to 4 parts and the parts are reordered so that the edges become parallel to X and Y axles. Often we use the same idea when building seamless fill patterns in 2D vector graphics software:

In the left 2 vertical planes are inserted. In the middle the surface element is sliced to 4 parts. One of the parts is moved apart to show it's separated. In the right The pieces are duplicated and moved to have a new easily tileable element. The parts snap together perfectly, but they are NOT joined to one in this phase.
The items are duplicated again and 2 different joined versions are made:

The blue one is joined (=Boolean union) to one as is. It will be needed to make the straight cylindrical part of the final dome. The red one has the right half scaled to 70% in X-axis direction before joining. It is needed in the curved dome top.
In the next image both versions are copied to make a straight array.

The blue versions are copied as is. The red versions are scaled progressively to 70% in X-direction. Using the same percentage 70% leaves the crossings of the grooves straight.
In the next image the stripe is copied to 16 item array in Y-direction to have enough elements for the cylindrical surface:

In the same image the array is duplicated and bent to cylinder. The array is 16 x 8 millimeters wide. Dividing it by 2Pi gives the right outer radius of the cylinder. It's rounded to R = 21 millimeters. The base reference line and the bending reference circle are shown as yellow (=highlight in program Moi).
In the next image the red part of the cylinder is placed inside the base reference cylinder (greenish)  and a (guessed) curve is revolved to make the bending reference.

I must admit that

the number of the scaled sections in the red part is too low
the progressive scaling percentage 70% in X-direction is not the best possible approximation, it's only a guess.

The right numbers should be calculated. A mathematician probably finds them easily, but I'm not one. I can only try different numbers, but that's not 100% trial and error, because elementary math makes possible to calculate without drawing how well different numbers fit. Using the Solver function in Excel spreadsheet helps substantially finding the right numbers, because it can find a perfect combination automatically if one inputs at first something even as good as guessed above. I'll add an example to the end of the answer later.
In the next image the bending (= deformation "Flow" in program Moi) is done, the reference surfaces and the original red cylinder are moved aside, the bent red dome is placed at the end of the blue cylinder and scaled a little shorter for the best apparent continuity in the seam:

To see the result better the color is changed to slightly blueish grey and the rendering of all those black edge lines is suppressed.

The lack of proper math can be seen at the pole. The closest surface elements are still heavily distorted. Leaving the hole was a must for the same reason as in my 1st attempt (=to prevent the forming of a math singularity which would cause the program to hang forever or halt due a division by zero):

Inserting a small cylinder fills the hole, if needed.
How to use elementary math to find better numbers:
The next image shows the result:

And the next image has a zoomed in view of the dome pole area:

As you see, the sizes of the surface elements converge fast towards the pole. It's useless to continue closer the pole when the elements have smaller details than the resolution of the 3D printing method.
The next image shows it in single color and without any edge lines:

The next image contains a collection of math facts:

The progressively scaled stripe of surface elements has 10 elements (N=10). The fitting scaling factor k is about 78,7%, but the actually used k (found by Excel Solver) contains much more decimals. Rounding it too much causes visible cumulative error. With N=10 the radius of the hole (=R2) is about 2,4 millimeters, that's a little more than 10% of the 21 mm outer radius of the dome (=R1).The size of the smallest surface element at the edge of the hole is about 0,8 millimeters.
To use Excel the math equations were shuffled to calculate the hole diameter R2 in two ways; once by the length of the dome profile arc and once by the downscaling of the surface element size. The number of the progressively scaled surface elements in the still planar array (red) was set = 10 and Excel solver was used to find proper scaling factor k which minimizes the square of the difference of the versions of R2.
The equations of the versions of R2 were formed to fulfill the next 2 conditions:

The profile arc length of the spherical part of the dome must be the same as the total length of the array of planar progressively scaled surface elements

The smallest surface element size must be the same integral part (=1/16) of the circumference of the hole as the diagonal D is of the outer circumference of the dome.


The next image shows the on "profile arc length" based equation for R2:

The next image shows the on "scaling" based equation for R2:

To make the equations simpler it's assumed that R2 is so much smaller than R1 that R2 presents well the length of the missing part of the full 90 degrees dome profile arc.
Changing N from 10 to 11 reduces the hole radius  to 1,9 millimeters as shown in the next image:

There should be also some reduction of the surface element thickness towards the pole to avoid small surface elements which have large thickness variations, because 3D-printing such details is difficult and inserting a cork to the pole hole looks less offensive when the fine details gradually fade towards the hole. I skip it.
